# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'launch')

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am currently learning electron.js by building a simple application that scrapes data from a website. But there is this obnoxious and exasperating error that i am facing.

[Folder structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZkD1.png)

This is the preload.js file.

```
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");
const { puppeteer } = require("puppeteer");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("puppeteer", {
  launch: async (options) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
    return browser;
  },
  newPage: async (options) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options).newPage();
    return browser;
  },
});
```

This is the func.js file (this file contains the main function that scrapes data)

```
const main_link = async (url) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await puppeteer.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  // await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });
  const content = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let problem = document.querySelectorAll(".card .text-right a");
    let links = [];
    problem.forEach((element) => {
      links.push(element.href);
    });
    return links;
  });
  await browser.close();
  console.log(content);
};

main_link("https://example.com");
```

There are two html files (basically views). the first one is a simple form, i am just asking for some data like name, age. (i am just learning electron). I have added a button in the first html file, which connects it to the second html file (choose.html).

In the second, html file, i really want to use some data from a website. So this is the second file where i included the func.js file. (choose.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'" />
    <title>Choose</title>
    <script src="func.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

This is the error i am getting in the devtools (inside the application (electron))

[Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCd37.png)

It would be great, if someone could help me, I don't really know how to write good answers on stackoverflow, i will learn from this one for sure. I really want to make a solid project, but for that i will have to learn Electron.

I was trying to solve this error, but I think i am not that proficient in electron and backend.

Comment: At the point where the error occurs, the **puppeteer** variable is not set (undefined). Undefined has no method `launch()`. may by try this `const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
`

Comment: @SwaD Hey thanks for replying me. I setup puppeteer in the preload.js file, isn't that enough ? or am i missing something, if I am can you tell me a little about that, if you are free. Thank you

Comment: @SwaD when i am using require('something') it says "require is not defined. i am using this in the func.js file. basically the renderer

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference but you may want try `window.puppeteer.`... since contextBridge attaches the apiKey to the window object.

Comment: How are you creating your second window `choose.html`? If you are not creating it in your main process via [`new BrowserWindow();`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window) then your second window will not have access to your `preload.js` script and all the functions it contains, including the use of Node’s `require` in Puppeteer via your `func.js` script.

Answer (score 0):

For [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#4-enable-process-sandboxing) reasons, Electron's processes are [sandboxed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox) by default. For the preload, it means that you can only `require` some [specific modules](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox#preload-scripts) (emphasis mine):

> In order to allow renderer processes to communicate with the main process, preload scripts attached to sandboxed renderers will still have a polyfilled subset of Node.js APIs available. A `require` function similar to Node's `require` module is exposed, **but can only import a subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules**: [...]

If you want to use `puppeteer` and keep sandboxing, you have to `require` it on your main process and use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate between your processes:

**preload.js**

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("puppeteer", {
  launch: (options) => ipcRenderer.invoke('puppeteer:launch', options),
  newPage:(options) => ipcRenderer.invoke('puppeteer:newPage', options),
});
```

**main.js**

```
ipcMain.handle('puppeteer:launch', async (_event, options) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
  return browser;
});


ipcMain.handle('puppeteer:newPage', async (_event, options) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options).newPage();
  return browser;
});
```

If you don't care about sandboxing/security and want to keep calling `puppeteer` on the preload, you can disable `sandbox` in the `webPreferences` of your [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window):

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    sandbox: false,
    ...
  }
});
```

Also, on your renderer make sure you try to access the `puppeteer` functions exposed with `contextBridge` from the `window` object:

```
const { puppeteer } = window;
```